# iOS SwiftUI - pick image or video from gallery using PhotosPicker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use the new PhotosPicker:

```
PhotosPicker(
    selection: $selectedItem,
    matching: .videos,
    photoLibrary: .shared()) {
        Text("Select a photo")
    }
    .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newItem in
        Task {
            if let data = try? await newItem?.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) {
                selectedImageData = data
            }
        }
    }
```

how can I set to pick either image or video instead of only one of those?

I tried:

```
matching: [.images, .videos],
```

and get:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'PHPickerFilter?'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Solution

Noticing that the `matching` parameter is of type `PHPickerFilter`, you can use the `.any(of:)` static function to combine filters. For example:

```
PhotosPicker("Pick Photo",
             selection: $item,
             matching: .any(of: [.images, .videos])) // <- combine filters
```

or let's say you want to exclude a "type" filter

```
PhotosPicker("Pick Photo",
             selection: $item,
             matching: .any(of: [.images, .not(.videos)])) //<- Use the .not() to exclude filters
```

#### Example

Let's take a sample code I wrote:

```
// Other views...
VStack {
            // Pick either photos or videos
            PhotosPicker("Pick **EITHER** Photos or Videos", //<- Bonus tip: You can use markdowns in swift
                         selection: $item,
                         matching: .any(of: [.images, .videos]))
            
            // Filter out photos with the .not() function
            PhotosPicker("Pick **ONLY** Videos",
                         selection: $item,
                         matching: .any(of: [.videos, .not(.images)]))
        }
```

#### Results

| Simulator Gallery | variations of PhotoPicker in app |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

You can find the Apple documentation on the View [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/photospicker)

Comment: Works, there is just one ) too much in your code. Thanks!

Comment: `PhotosPicker` only available in iOS 16+ 