How can I filter the PhotoPicker to only show images, excluding videos and GIFs?
when using the PhotoPicker or UIImage, I can't restrict the picker to show only images, and excluding videos and GIFs.
struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Filter to display only images (still includes GIFs)
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UTType.image.identifier]
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let selectedImageURL = info[.imageURL] as? URL {
                // Check if the selected file is a GIF
                if selectedImageURL.pathExtension.lowercased() == "gif" {
                    print("GIFs are not allowed.")
                    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                }
            }
            
            if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                // Process the selected image
                print(selectedImage)
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
    }
}

I’m using UIImagePickerController in Swift to allow users to select images, but it still shows GIFs. I want to completely exclude GIFs from being displayed in the picker.
I found out that GIFs are categorized as images on iOS.

You can't do it. You would have to create your own custom picker. I have no idea why there are GIFs in your photo library, though. The camera does not take GIF photos.

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961615/ios-swiftui-pick-image-or-video-from-gallery-using-photospicker

I don't think this is possible using the picker.
As someone else suggested in the comments, you're better off building your own photo picker and fetching the photos using Apple's PhotoKit framework.
